# How to create a JSON Object and pass it in a REST API call?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd-module

I am new with Erlang and my doubt is how to create a JSON Object in Erlang and pass that object in REST API call. I have read so many posts but didn't get any satisfying answer.

**Edit**

Here I am calling the API:

```
offline_message(From, To, #message{type = Type, body = Body}) ->
Type = xml:get_text(Type),
Body = xml:get_text(Body),
Token = gen_mod:get_module_opt(To#jid.lserver, ?MODULE, auth_token, fun(S) -> iolist_to_binary(S) end, list_to_binary("")),
PostUrl = gen_mod:get_module_opt(To#jid.lserver, ?MODULE, post_url, fun(S) -> iolist_to_binary(S) end, list_to_binary("")),
to = To#jid.luser
from = From#jid.luser
if
    (Type == <<"chat">>) and (Body /= <<"">>) ->
        Sep = "&",
        Post = {
            "token":binary_to_list(Token),
            "from":binary_to_list(from),
            "to":binary_to_list(to),
            "body":binary_to_list(Body)
        },
        ?INFO_MSG("Sending post request to ~s with body \"~s\"", [PostUrl, Post]),
        httpc:request(post, {binary_to_list(PostUrl), [], "application/json", binary_to_list(Post)},[],[]),
        ok;
    true ->
        ok
end.
```

Is everything ok here regarding JSON String. I am trying to modify this [module](https://github.com/diamondbybold/ejabberd_mod_offline_post/blob/master/mod_offline_post.erl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to create a JSON Object in Erlang

There are no such things as objects in erlang, so the simple answer is: you can't.  However, the things you send over *the wire* are just strings, and you can certainly create strings using erlang.

To make things easier, you can use an erlang module like [jsx](https://github.com/talentdeficit/jsx) to create the json formatted strings that you want to send in your request.  However, in order to use erlang modules you will have to learn a little about `rebar3`, which is erlang's package installer (see [What is the easiest way for beginners to install a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278982/what-is-the-easiest-way-for-beginners-to-install-a-module)).

Remember that an http request is just a string that is formatted a certain way.  An http request starts with a line like:

```
POST /some/path HTTP/1.1
```

Then there are some lines of text called *headers*, which look like:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla-yah-yah-bah
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 103
```

Then there are a couple of newlines followed by some additional text, which is called the *post body,* which can be in several different formats (the format should be declared in the `Content-Type` header):

```
    Format                 Content-Type
    ------                 -----------
   "x=1&y=2"               application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   "{x:1, y:2}"            application/json
   "more complex string"   multipart/form-data
```

To make it easier to assemble an http request and send it to a server, erlang has a builtin *http client* called `inets`, which you can read about in the docs [here](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/inets/http_client.html).  For an example that uses `inets`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48973601/inets-httpc-client-example-in-users-guide-not-working).  Because `inets` is a bit cumbersome to use, alternatively you can use a third party http client like [hackney](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney).  Once again, though, you will need to be able to install `hackney` with `rebar3`.

Once you send the request, it's up to the server to decipher the request and take the necessary course of action.

Comment: Hi is there any way by which I can create a JSON string without using any module, please check my question I have updated My question

Comment: @VirendraVarma, Sure.  Here is an example: `"{\"a\": 1, \"b\": 2}"`. The real question is what type of data does the http client require? In the code you posted, the line starting with `Post =` is not written in erlang. What was there before?

Comment: @VirendraVarma, I looked at the code at the link you posted, and the Post variable should be assigned a list of strings, or you can also assign Post a list containing one string.  In general, erlang's io modules don't care whether they get a list containing the entire string, or a list containing many segments of the string.